# How to resume a argo-workflow only if it is already in suspended state?

Tags: argo-workflows

I can suspend a workflow using `argo suspend` ([Suspend](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/cli/argo_suspend/#argo-suspend)), and I can resume the workflow again by `argo-resume` ([Resume](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/cli/argo_resume/#argo-resume))

However, while resuming, argo-workflows makes no checks on whether the workflow is already in a suspended state. How can this be imposed from the client side?

In summary, I only want to resume a workflow if it has already gone into a suspended state. If it has not gone into suspended state, I will wait for the workflow to get suspended, and resume only thereafter.

I tried using `workflow.Status.Phase` ([Status](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/fields/#workflowstatus)) to check the state of workflow before resuming, however, the Phase string only has "Running" field, which does not differentiate between a running workflow and a suspended workflow.([Phase String code](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/4e450e250168e6b4d51a126b784e90b11a0162bc/pkg/apis/workflow/v1alpha1/workflow_phase.go#L9))

Answer (score 0):

I think to be checked values of type and state.
If running, type is Suspend and state is Running.
If Task completed, Value of state will change as succeeded value (e.g)

```
curl https://localhost:2746/api/v1/workflows/argo -H "Authorization: $ARGO_TOKEN" -k | jq '.items[].status.nodes[] | select(.type=="Suspend" and .phase=="Running")'
```